# Stretch the Checkbox to the cell size

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid

I'm using WPF and have DataGrid with checkbox column.
the problem is that I would like the checkbox to stretch and fill the cell

[image]

this is my XAML :

```
 <Grid>
    <Controls:DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <Controls:DataGrid.Columns>
            <Controls:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
            <Controls:DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <Controls:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <CheckBox />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Controls:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </Controls:DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </Controls:DataGrid.Columns>
    </Controls:DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can put the `CheckBox` in a [`Viewbox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.viewbox.aspx), there will still be a small margin though which probably belongs to some control's `Template`, you could either try and change that template or mess with the `Margin` if you want to.

```
<Viewbox Margin="-1">
    <CheckBox/>
</Viewbox>
```